# Is it good practice to use firebase-admin-sdk and firebase-ui + firebase-client-sdk together to handle servver-side and client-side authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to create auth mechanism for my `Next.js` project. Mainly, I want to use `firebase-auth` and `firestore`. I want to have important logic on server side for security reasons. I don't want to expose user roles to client side, but have APIs respond appropriately for specific use roles.

What is best practice, or How can I use Google provider and passwordless sign-in on server-side? Or is it even possible?

Not sure exactly how to do this, but I have already included `firebase-admin` in project and I can create logic to verify user based on API headers. But not sure how should I handle client-side?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use Google provider and passwordless sign-in on server-side? Or is it even possible?

You can use [Firebase Client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to authenticate users with Firebase Authentication and then set a [session cookie](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) created by Admin SDK so you can get user's information on server side before rendering the page. 
Essentially, you add an API that takes user's Firebase token after login/sign-up to create the cookie.

> I can create logic to verify user based on API headers. But not sure how should I handle client-side?

You'll have to retain users information in application state from server. While you can keep user authenticated with client SDK as well, I would recommend using only one method i.e. cookies for a SSR app. So do set the [auth persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) to `inMemoryPersistence` that'll clear client side state on reload.

Do ensure that you do no expose any Admin SDK credentials/instances to client side.

Answer (score 0):

it seems most of the guys use `firebase-admin` for handling backend and `firebase` client SDK for handling front end.

However, you can create users on your own backend as well using admin auth API documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

When you manage users yourself, you have full control over users data and remember, with great capabilities comes great responsibility!

You can do something like this

```
getAuth()
  .createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: false,
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

But using client side SDK should just make things much easier. Hope it helps.